# SQLite with java not storing the data

Tags: java, sqlite

I am trying to write an application that will store a list of TV shows and i am using SQLite to do this, I seem to be able to read back any of the data inserted as long as i dont stop and start the program, if i do that then the database is read like there is nothing in there. Auto commit is enabled to. And i am pretty sure something is getting written because when i open the .db file i am able to see the values i saved in there. Here is the code i am using to communicate with the database

```
package DatabaseHelper;

import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class ShowDatabaseHelper extends DatabaseHelper<String>
{

    public ShowDatabaseHelper(String dbpath) throws SQLException 
    {
        super(dbpath);

        // Create table
        stmt = con.createStatement();
        stmt.execute("create table if not exists shows(showname varchar)");
        stmt.close();
    }

    public boolean insert(String showTitle) throws SQLException 
    {
        stmt = con.createStatement();

        // Check wether the show is allready in the table
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("select * from shows where showname = '" + showTitle + "'");
        stmt.close();
        if( rs.getFetchSize() != 0 ) return false;

    stmt = con.createStatement();
        stmt.executeUpdate("insert into shows(showname) values('" + showTitle + "')");
        //con.commit();
        stmt.close();

        return true;
    }

    public void update( String current, String replacement ) throws SQLException 
    {
    stmt = con.createStatement();
        stmt.executeUpdate("update shows set showname = '" + replacement + "' where showname = '" + current + "'");
        //con.commit();
        stmt.close();
    }

    public void remove( String data ) throws SQLException 
    {
        stmt = con.createStatement();
        stmt.executeUpdate("delete from shows where showname = '" + data + "'");
        //con.commit();
        stmt.close();
    }

    public String[] select() throws SQLException 
    {
        String[] shows;
        stmt = con.createStatement();

        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("select * from shows");

        stmt.close();

        if( rs.getFetchSize() == 0 ) return null;

        shows = new String[rs.getFetchSize()-1];

        //rs.first();
        for( int i = 0; i < rs.getFetchSize(); i++ )
        {
            shows[i] = rs.getString("showname");
            rs.next();
        }

        return shows;
    }

    @Override
    public void clear() throws SQLException 
    {
        stmt = con.createStatement();
        stmt.executeUpdate("truncate shows");
        //con.commit();
        stmt.close();
    }

}
```

And the super class this extends from is the following

```
package DatabaseHelper;

import java.sql.*;

public abstract class DatabaseHelper<T>
{
    protected Connection con = null;
    protected Statement stmt = null;

    /**
     * Opens a connection to the database in question
     * 
     * @param dbpath
     * @throws SQLException
     * @throws ClassNotFoundException 
     */
    public DatabaseHelper(String dbpath) throws SQLException
    {
        con = DriverManager.getConnection(dbpath);
        System.out.println(con.getAutoCommit());
    }

    /**
     * Clears the database
     * 
     * @throws SQLException
     */
    public abstract void clear() throws SQLException;

    /**
     * Closes the connection to the database
     * 
     * @throws SQLException
     */
    public void close() throws SQLException
    {
        //con.commit();
        con.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: It is set to true, when ever i tried to do a commit manually it would throw an error and say that auto commit was enabled

Comment: Are you closing the database connection before exiting your program (and are you sure ;))?

Comment: Pretty sure, when the GUI is closed a function is called that closes the connection with the database before the window is disposed of

Answer (score 0):

I see nothing in that code that sets auto commit. My advice would be to add back in the explicit commits.

I think if you do that when auto commit is on, you'll get an exception so it's a way to check your assertion.

Otherwise, add in the code to set auto commit, i find that's safer than relying on assumptions.

You can also temporarily add debug statements to your close method (and others) to ensure it's being called.

And you may also want to examine (and show us) the code that's calling these methods. Witout that, we can't tell what's happening in sequence. For all we know, you're calling the method with `truncate` in it before you exit :-)